# Jinja2 not finding json object attributes

Tags: python, html, json, jinja2

I have this code in my html file:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                {% for project in projects_using_each_technique[loop.index - 1] %}
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('show_project', id=1) }}"><h3>{{ project }}</h3>{{project.short_description}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

For some reason Jinja2 doesnt find the attributes like `project.short_description`, but writes out the whole project, all the attributes, when I write just `project` as I've done just above, which contains `project.short_description`.
So it has access to the project but can't access it's attributes or what? Im quite unsure what's the problem as it worked like 10 minutes ago..

The whole project looks like this:

```
[{'techniques_used': ['ada', 'python'], 'course_id': 'TDP003', 'project_id': 2, 'small_image': 'X', 'big_image': 'XXX', 'lulz_had': 'medium', 'course_name': 'OKÄNT', 'academic_credits': 'WUT?', 'group_size': 6, 'external_link': 'YY', 'end_date': '2009-09-09', 'short_description': 'no', 'start_date': '2009-09-08', 'project_name': '2007', 'long_description': 'no no no'}]
```

There are 3 more that has all the same attributes

Comment: Could you please share the output of your whole printed project?

Answer (score 2):

you can access like this

```
project['short_description']
```

Comment: I still get the same error saying list object has no attribute called short_description

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, its a dictionary in a list that's why it couldnt find it, now that I always adress that it's in a list it works. Curious why it worked before though, as I got the same result as I want and have now that it's fixed without me adressing that it's in a list.